# Shopify: Show a message when selected variant is out of stock

Tags: jquery, html, css, shopify

I need to add an out of stock message when a product variant(color & size) is selected on my product's page.

I've found this piece of code that does this but it only looks at the default product variant when first viewing the product's page and the message is static:

```
{% assign variant = product.variants.first %}
{% if variant.inventory_quantity <= 0 and variant.available and variant.inventory_management != '' %}
<p style="color:#ff0000" class="notice">This item is currently out of stock. I will take up to 3 weeks to ship.</p> 
{% endif %}
```

What I need this to do is have the message act according to the variant that is selected.

I know that there's probably some java script involved but I'm but I'm fairly new to this.

I've found an example website that has exactly what I'm looking for:
http://www.missesdressy.com/dresses/designers/blush-by-alexia/9388_1?track=39549527.r.1

When the customer selects their size and color variant it shows a message if the item is ready to ship or requires a special order, also as well as showing the available/special order/sold out wording on the variant's drop-down selector.

I would probably just be happy with just the message showing up accordingly though.

So this is the javascript that I found from my product_form.liquid in my theme that controls the variant selector.  Not sure how to modify it at this point.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // <![CDATA[  
    $(function() {    
      $product = $('#product-' + {{ product.id }});
      new Shopify.OptionSelectors("product-select-{{ product.id }}", { product: {{ product | json }}, onVariantSelected: selectCallback });

      {% if product.available %}
        {% assign found_one_in_stock = false %}
        {% for variant in product.variants %}
          {% if variant.available and found_one_in_stock == false %}
            {% assign found_one_in_stock = true %}
            {% for option in product.options %}
              $('.single-option-selector:eq(' + {{ forloop.index0 }} + ')', $product).val({{ variant.options[forloop.index0] | json }}).trigger('change');
            {% endfor %}
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    });
  // ]]>
</script>
```

And this is from my app.js.liquid that is maybe apart of the script too?

```
    }

if (variant && variant.available == true) {
  if(variant.price < variant.compare_at_price){
    $('.was_price', $product).html(Shopify.formatMoney(variant.compare_at_price, $('form.product_form', $product).data('money-format')))        
  } else {
    $('.was_price', $product).text('')
  } 
  $('.current_price', $product).html(Shopify.formatMoney(variant.price, $('form.product_form', $product).data('money-format')));
  $('#add-to-cart', $product).removeClass('disabled').removeAttr('disabled').val('Add to Cart');
  $notify_form.hide();
} else {
  var message = variant ? "{{ settings.sold_out_text }}" : "Out of Stock";    
  $('.was_price', $product).text('')
  $('.current_price', $product).text(message);
  $('#add-to-cart', $product).addClass('disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled').val(message); 
  $notify_form.fadeIn();
}  };
```

Answer (score 1):

See [this tutorial](http://www.tetchi.ca/shopify-theme-from-scratch-part-5/) (section 5. Plug in selectCallback). It says to put the below code in product.liquid. The [demo site](https://basic-theme.myshopify.com/collections/frontpage/products/awesome-sneakers) for this tutorial shows how this code changes the price field to say "Sold Out" or "Unavailable" if the variant does not exist.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  // <![CDATA[  
var selectCallback = function(variant, selector) {
  if (variant && variant.available == true) {
    // selected a valid variant
    jQuery('.purchase').removeClass('disabled').removeAttr('disabled'); // remove unavailable class from add-to-cart button, and re-enable button
    jQuery('.price-field').html(Shopify.formatMoney(variant.price, "{{shop.money_with_currency_format}}"));  // update price field
  } else {
    // variant doesn't exist
    jQuery('.purchase').addClass('disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled');      // set add-to-cart button to unavailable class and disable button
    var message = variant ? "Sold Out" : "Unavailable";    
    jQuery('.price-field').text(message); // update price-field message
  }
};

// initialize multi selector for product
jQuery(function() {
  new Shopify.OptionSelectors("product-select", { product: {{ product | json }}, onVariantSelected: selectCallback });
  jQuery('.selector-wrapper').addClass('clearfix');
  {% if product.options.size == 1 %}
  jQuery('.selector-wrapper').prepend("<label for='product-select-option-0'>{{ product.options.first }}</label>");
  {% endif %}
});
// ]]>
</script>
```

**EDIT:**

> *I'm not sure how to use it to display the message that I want based on variant quantity.*

I've modified the above code with the if statement in your question (see below). This should be very close to what you want. Note that `variant.available` will be false if the product is sold out, so leave that out of your if statement.

```
var selectCallback = function(variant, selector) {
  if (variant && variant.inventory_management != '' && variant.inventory_quantity <= 0) 
  {
    jQuery('.price-field').html('<p style="color:#ff0000" class="notice">This item is currently out of stock. I will take up to 3 weeks to ship.</p>');  // update price field
  }
};
```

> *Also I think this doesn't allow customers to order the variant if it's out of stock. I want to allow customers to order the variant even if it's out of stock when I set that option.*

If you want to allow customers to purchase a product even if it's out of stock, simply remove the line that disables the purchase button:

```
jQuery('.purchase').addClass('disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled');      // set add-to-cart button to unavailable class and disable button
```

Comment: I think my theme already has this feature.  I'm not sure how to use it to display the message that I want based on variant quantity.  Also I think this doesn't allow customers to order the variant if it's out of stock.  I want to allow customers to order the variant even if it's out of stock when I set that option.

Comment: I've added the javascript that's already in my theme, that I think covers the variant selector.  Not sure how to modify it though.